# Not able to shutdown the jms listener which posts message to kafka spring boot application with Runtime.exit, context.close, System.exit()

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jms, spring-kafka

I am developing a spring boot application which will listen to ibm mq with

```
@JmsListener(id="abc", destination="${queueName}", containerFactory="defaultJmsListenerContainerFactory")
```

I have a `JmsListenerEndpointRegistry` which starts the `listenerContainer`.

On message  will try to push the same message with some business logic to kafka. The poster code is

```
 kafkaTemplate.send(kafkaProp.getTopic(), uniqueId, message)
```

Now in case a kafka producer fails, I want my boot application to get terminated. So I have added a custom

```
setErrorHandler.
```

So I have tried

```
    `System.exit(1)`, `configurableApplicationContextObject.close()`, `Runtime.getRuntime.exit(1)`.
```

But none of them work. Below is the log that gets generated after 
        `System.exit(0)` or above others.

```
2018-05-24 12:12:47.981  INFO 18904 --- [       Thread-4] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@1d08376: startup date [Thu May 24 12:10:35 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-05-24 12:12:48.027  INFO 18904 --- [       Thread-4] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 2147483647
2018-05-24 12:12:48.028  INFO 18904 --- [       Thread-4] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 0
2018-05-24 12:12:48.028  INFO 18904 --- [       Thread-4] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2018-05-24 12:12:48.028  INFO 18904 --- [       Thread-4] o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms.
2018-05-24 12:12:48.044  INFO 18904 --- [       Thread-4] o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 30000 ms.
```

But the application is still running and below are the running threads

```
Daemon Thread [Tomcat JDBC Pool Cleaner[14341596:1527144039908]] (Running)  
Thread [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1] (Running)    
Thread [DestroyJavaVM] (Running)    
Daemon Thread [JMSCCThreadPoolMaster] (Running) 
Daemon Thread [RcvThread: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection@12474910[qmid=*******,fap=**,channel=****,ccsid=***,sharecnv=***,hbint=*****,peer=*******,localport=****,ssl=****]] (Running) 
Thread [Thread-4] (Running)
```

The help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance. I simply want the application should exit.

Below is the thread dump before I call `System.exit(1)`

```
"DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1" 
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at sun.management.ThreadImpl.getThreadInfo1(Native Method)
        at sun.management.ThreadImpl.getThreadInfo(ThreadImpl.java:174)
        at com.QueueErrorHandler.handleError(QueueErrorHandler.java:42)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeErrorHandler(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:931)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.handleListenerException(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:902)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:326)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:235)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1166)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1158)
        at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1055)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of solutions which worked for me to solve above.

Solutions 1.
Get all threads in error handler and interrupt them all and then exist the system.

```
ThreadMXBean threadMXBean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
ThreadInfo[] threadInfos = threadMXBean.getThreadInfo(threadMXBean.getAllThreadIds(), 100);

for (ThreadInfo threadInfo : threadInfos) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
System.exit(1);
```

Solution 2. Define a application context manager. Like

```
public class AppContextManager implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext _appCtx;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx){
         _appCtx = ctx;
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getAppContext(){
        return _appCtx;
    } 

    public static void exit(Integer exitCode) {
        System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(_appCtx,() -> exitCode));
    }
}
```

Then use same manager to exit in error handler

```
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    jmsListenerEndpointRegistry.stop();
                    AppContextManager.exit(-1);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a thread dump to see what `Thread [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1] (Running)` is doing.

> Now in case a kafka producer fails

What kind of failure? If the broker is down, the thread will block in the producer library for up to 60 seconds by default.

You can reduce that time by setting the `max.block.ms` producer property.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I want the application to fail in case my producer fails to post on kafka. It might be a broker failure as well. 

I tried with 

    `ProducerConfig.MAX_BLOCK_MS_CONFIG, 500`

But no luck.

Comment: Don't put stuff like that in comments - it's unreadable - edit your question instead to add the thread dump. Include the thread name etc.